# IS Self Service Site creation work in the Cross farm configuration

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, user-profile-service, self-service, cross-farm

We have a problem with UPA in cross farm scenario in SharePoint 2016 ( April 2018 CU).

- We configure the UPA in Farm A (where everything is working as expected). MySites also in Farm A
- Build a Trust between Farm A and Farm B
- Consume the UPA & MMS from Farm A in Farm B
- In Farm B, we enable to configure the Self-Service Site creation for any web application. When we click the self service site creation link in Ribbon we encountered following error

> " Sorry, something went wrong 
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.UserProfileApplication has null upa "

- In ULS logs following entry

> "Application error when access /_admin/ConfigSSC.aspx,
>   Error=UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.UserProfileApplication has null upa

"
I checked the permission of Farm account & App pool account of Farm B on UPA in farm A, trust is healthy as other functions & MMS is working as expected. I have attached the ULS logs with verbosex level.

I tried the same scenario in different set of farms but no luck.

What i am missing here? is this scenario supported?